# Automapper - Ignore property on base class

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, automapper-2

I'm having difficulty ignoring a property on an class which inherits from a base class.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<FormViewModelBase, EntityBase>()
.Include<FormViewModel, Entity>()
.ForMember(x => x.Id, o => o.Ignore());

Mapper.CreateMap<FormViewModel, Entity>();
```

The only thing to note here is that the property on the base class is String and the property on the derived class is a Int32.

No matter what, when i try map an instance of FormViewModel to Entity the String based Id property on the Entity class is always set to the Int value from the FormViewModel, even though i have specified to ignore it.

The reason I am using different types for the Id on FormViewModel and Entity, is that I am using RavenDB in a web app and objects can be loaded via a string or an int Id. On the client-side Int Id's are preferred as the standard Raven string based ID's do not play well when generating links.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is here ?

Comment: Might also be helpful to know I am mapping to an existing object.

Answer (score 1):

So your base class looks something like this?

```
public class FormViewModelBase
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   // other stuff
}
```

and your derived class looks like this?

```
public class FormViewModel : FormViewModelBase
{
   public new int Id { get; set; }
   // other stuff
}
```

I'm assuming that's the case.

And if that's the case, then the derived Id is hiding the base Id property.

Anyway, so are you passing around actual instances of a `FormViewModel` and making `Entity` objects from them?

I see this line:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<FormViewModel, Entity>();
```

Which says to me "make me a new `Entity` object from the `FormViewModel` object I send you and do the default, conventional thing to accomplish this."

So when you call something like:

```
var anEntity = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<FormViewModel, Entity>(aFormViewModel);
```

It's going to use that Map, not the one for the base object.  Because it *is* a derived `FormViewModel`.

If you did something like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<FormViewModel, Entity>()
.ForMember(x => x.Id, o => o.Ignore());
```

to handle the mapping of your derived object, it would map it, I suspect, as you would want but it might be helpful to understand a bit more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Simply, im trying to map a model posted from a form to an entity that will be saved in my DB. The FormViewModelBase has a property Id (Int32) and the FormViewModel inherits from this. The FormViewModel class does not specify a new Id property it just uses the Id from its base class, plus some other properties. I want to Ignore the Id when mapping from FormViewModel --> Entity. The mapping code i provided above does not work for me, the property on my Entity is always overwritten.

Comment: OK, so FormViewModel doesn't have an Id but Entity has one you want to preserve.  Gotcha.   In my test code, the last bit of code I wrote there that does the Ignore on Id when mapping a FormViewModel to and Entity will preserve Entity's original Id.

Comment: Ok, yes that is my work around, but according to the Automapper documentation i should be able to Ignore the Id on the base class mapping so i dont have to specify the Ignore rule on each subclass mapping.

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Mapping-inheritance it looks like the problem is that convention (e.g., Id => Id) is higher than that ignore.

Comment: @itsmatt IMHO, that last comment is the "real" answer to the question.  Much appreciated if you would consider editing your answer to put that at the top.  I nearly overlooked the comments down here when looking for an answer to the same problem from the OP.  It sounds like the OPer agrees that it's the "real" answer too.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify mapping details (like ignoring certain properties) in the mapping of **child classes**, not parents. For example:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ParentA, ParentB>
      .Include<ChildA, ChildB>();

Mapper.CreateMap<ChildA, ChildB>
      .ForMember(dest => dest.SomeProperty, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

The reason your code is not working is that you're specifying Ignore() on the parent mappings.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a year old but I haven't found a solution in SO that answers this kind of questions. I had identical issue and after some digging the only thing I found is that this behavior is not very well documented. And mapping base classes works but ignoring them doesn't for some reason.

I used this extension method and it worked out for me

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination>
        InheritMappingFromBaseType<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
    {
        var sourceType = typeof(TSource);
        var desctinationType = typeof(TDestination);
        var sourceParentType = sourceType.BaseType;
        var destinationParentType = desctinationType.BaseType;

        expression
            .ForAllMembers(x => x.Condition(r => NotAlreadyMapped(sourceParentType, destinationParentType, r)));

        return expression;
    }

    private static bool NotAlreadyMapped(Type sourceType, Type desitnationType, ResolutionContext r)
    {
        return !r.IsSourceValueNull &&
               Mapper.FindTypeMapFor(sourceType, desitnationType).GetPropertyMaps().Where(
                   m => m.DestinationProperty.Name.Equals(r.MemberName)).Select(y => !y.IsMapped()).All(b => b);
    }
```

And this is how it's used (Notice that you will need to but the ignore declaration in the base classes mapping)

```
CreateMap<DerivedClassSource, DerivedClassDestination>()
            .InheritMappingFromBaseType()
```

What it does is mapping any properties that were not mapped using the base class mapping. In other words it breaks the default mapping priorities.

I found the source code [here](http://matthewmanela.com/blog/inheriting-base-type-mappings-with-automapper-extension/) and modified it a bit because some of the original method's code is now implemented in AutoMapper 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

After raising this as an issue with AutoMapper, the reason that Ignore is not added using Include is because there is no way to un-ignore - mappings can still be overridden in the base class.

The only way that you can currently achieve this behaviour is to decorate the destination property with the `[IgnoreMap]` attribute, but this will likely be inconsistent with the rest of your configuration, so you'd need to decide whether it's worth it!